# Emacs and ansi-term: Elisp iterate through a list of buffers

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using the following code, to open ansi-term. I found this [here](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2008/12/26/emacs-ansi-term-tricks/).

```
(require 'term)
(defun visit-ansi-term ()
  "If the current buffer is:
     1) a running ansi-term named *ansi-term*, rename it.
     2) a stopped ansi-term, kill it and create a new one.
     3) a non ansi-term, go to an already running ansi-term
        or start a new one while killing a defunt one"
  (interactive)
  (let ((is-term (string= "term-mode" major-mode))
        (is-running (term-check-proc (buffer-name)))
        (term-cmd "/usr/local/bin/bash")
        (anon-term (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")))
    (if is-term
        (if is-running
            (if (string= "*ansi-term*" (buffer-name))
                (call-interactively 'rename-buffer)
              (if anon-term
                  (switch-to-buffer "*ansi-term*")
                (ansi-term term-cmd)))
          (kill-buffer (buffer-name))
          (ansi-term term-cmd))
      (if anon-term
          (if (term-check-proc "*ansi-term*")
              (switch-to-buffer "*ansi-term*")
            (kill-buffer "*ansi-term*")
            (ansi-term term-cmd))
        (ansi-term term-cmd)))))
```

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'visit-ansi-term)`

Now I want to modify this, such that after renaming a buffer it remembers its name and when I use a keyboard shortcut to iterate through the renamed buffers list.

so if I press [F2] and it finds that ansi-term is running, it asks me if I want to rename it. I rename it to say, *BUILD*. I would like a function and bind to Say [F3] to iterate thorough the list of ansi-terms opened.

I'm a ELISP illiterate. would be glad it someone pointed be references which might help me doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code/binding cycles through all the buffers whose major mode is `term-mode`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f3>") 'cycle-ansi-term)
(defun cycle-ansi-term ()
  "cycle through buffers whose major mode is term-mode"
  (interactive)
  (when (string= "term-mode" major-mode)
    (bury-buffer))
  (let ((buffers (cdr (buffer-list))))
    (while buffers
      (when (with-current-buffer (car buffers) (string= "term-mode" major-mode))
        (switch-to-buffer (car buffers))
        (setq buffers nil))
      (setq buffers (cdr buffers)))))
```

Comment: @Tery Jackson: Hi, When I first tried this I tried with only 2 terms which works fine... but with multiple terms like this:                                                              . * another                 20  Term: char run
  * other                   20  Term: char run    
  * some                    19  Term: char run                      this loops through only 2 of the recently opened buffers... How do I remove this limitation? Thanks.

Comment: @Tery Jackson: Thanks a lot... now it loops through all the open ansi-term buffers. Thanks again.